# .NET6 target framework and precompiler check for net6.0-windows

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

If we define `<TargetFrameworks>` in the .csproj like

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net6.0;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I can define different dependency packages like

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />    
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
     ...
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows'">
     ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

And check in the code with precompiler statements to use different library (version) features

```
#if (NETSTANDARD2_0)
#endif

#if (NET6_0)
#endift
```

Works ...

But how do I check explicitly for target framework net6.0-windows?
(Unfortunatly) I need differences between Net6.0 and Net6.0-windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find `#if WINDOWS`, or `#if WINDOWS && NET6_0` work for your needs (maybe consider `NET6_0_OR_GREATER`, note); otherwise, you can define your own symbol:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);YOUR_THING</DefineConstants> 
</ItemGroup>
```

and use `#if YOUR_THING`

Comment: thx for the hint with DefineContants

Comment: thank you very much
hopefully next year I am able to write you new mails about Protobuf Any.
Merry Christmas and a happy new year.

Comment: @monty I'll keep an eye out for that